# How to query one customer with his referral customer and display all of their transactions

Tags: mysql

I have customer and transaction table

```
Customer Table
Name          |  Invited_by
John Doe      |  Jenny Grey
Mad Max       |  John Doe
Jayson Lu     |  Mad Max
Mark Green    |  Jenny Gray
Martin Su     |  Jenny Gray
Gwenn Stacy   |  John Doe
```

.

```
Transaction Table
Name          |   Product
John Doe      |   PS1
Mad Max       |   PS2
Mark Green    |   Xbox
Martin Su     |   TV
Jayson Lu     |   Xbox
Gwenn Stacy   |   TV
```

Is it possible to use the data from a result query and store it in the array to use for another query? or is there another way?

```
SELECT Customer.Name FROM Customer WHERE invited_by = "John Doe"
```

and use the result query as an array to my next query

I want to display all of **John Doe's** purchase and all of his invites purchase and also his invites-invites

```
Result
Name          |  Product
John Doe      |  PS1
Mad Max       |  PS2
Jayson Lu     |  Xbox
Gwenn Stacy   |  TV
```

The level of invites-invite will eventually increase.
MySQL Version 5.7

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from transaction where name in (SELECT Customer.Name FROM Customer WHERE invited_by = "John Doe")
```

I used a subquery to achieve what you desire,
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the query and i think it only returns the customer who were invited by John Doe which is Mad Max but the other customer who were invited by Mad Max was not shown.